# getting internet using networkmanager in linux based yocto

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, device, yocto

I installed modemmanager and networkmanager in linux based yocto . but i am not able to connect internet

```
 follow commands a below :-
 1) systemctl start Networkmanager.
 2) systemctl enable Networkmanager.
 3) mmcli -L
 4) mmcli -m 0 -e
 5) nmcli connection edit type gsm con-name "My GPRS Connection"
 6) nmcli > set gsm.apn internet
 7) nmcli > save
```

in networkmanager status command i am not getting ttyUSB2 interface for quectel module.

pleae help.